# Record the source of job dispatch

Tags: laravel

I'm curious if you guys know any easy and reliable way to track the source of what dispatched a Laravel job.

My use case for this is that I often have to debug failing jobs and knowing why, where and how they were dispatched would be very useful, e.g. could add it as metadata to Sentry reports.

I mean adding a property to a job would probably do it, but I'm wondering if there's some way that would not involve code changes in individual jobs.

Answer (score 2):

I think you're looking for **Job Events** ([Laravel documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queues#job-events))

You could add this to your **app/Providers/AppServiceProvider.php** -  **boot()** method or you could create one **QueueJobProvider** for example and add your provider in **config/app.php** inside the '**providers**' key.

With this events you can have the payload as you want and more proprities. You can learn more about this issue in Laravel docs [here](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queues#job-events)

```
use Illuminate\Queue\Events\JobProcessed;
use Illuminate\Queue\Events\JobProcessing;
use Illuminate\Queue\Events\JobFailed;
use Illuminate\Queue\Events\JobExceptionOccurred;    

Queue::before(function (JobProcessing $event) {
    // \Log::info($event);
    // \Log::info($event->job->payload());
});

Queue::after(function (JobProcessed $event) {
    // \Log::info($event);
    // \Log::info($event->job->payload());
});

Queue::failing(function (JobFailed $event) {
    // \Log::info($event);
    // \Log::info($event->job->payload());
});

Queue::exceptionOccurred(function (JobExceptionOccurred $event) {
    // \Log::info($event);
    // \Log::info($event->job->payload());
});
```

Comment: Yes, those are very useful, but I don't think they quite solve my need. They way I understand it, they're called with job objects that are already in the queue which gives me no way to know where in code the job was dispatched. The only thing I can think of at the moment is dumping part of the stack trace in the job constructor, but that feels very hacky.